# Not able to point my grails application to Dev environment

Tags: sql-server, grails, grails-2.0, grails-plugin, grails-controller

In `config.groovy`, i changed the value of server which it was pointing to, from local to Dev as below

```
cmpny.tx.app.server.url = "http://epdev5.austin.cmpny.com"
```

but still it is calling a local Url only, which is,

```
http://epvmrh6.americas.cmpny.net
```

I don't know from which file it is taking that value...

I saw that URL in the console as,

```
POST request failed (uri: Local URL, code: 500, reason: Internal Server Error) - Content: TargetName=ViewCart-View&jsonString=%5B%5D
```

Comment: Did you restart your application?

Comment: yes micha,i restarted and saw several times but no use

Comment: can you be more specific on your question? frankly, I didn't understand anything...

Comment: Posting your config.groovy would be helpful. How does your config.groovy distinguish between local and development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

friends i found out out from where it was taking the value.
It is taking from `Elite-config.groovy` which will be there in the folder

```
`C:\Users\name\.grails`
```

I have specified Dev server in these files so now it is taking value from Dev database.
Thanku